# How to find nodes with string type property in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a label `Users` which has a property `userid`. So I want to fetch all nodes which have string type `userid`. Is it possible?

Like:

```
MATCH (n:Users) where n.userid IS string RETURN n
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box feature to check data types in Neo4j, but you can implicitly check if a given value is a string trying to convert to string and comparing to the original value, like this:

```
match (n:Users)
where toString(n.userid) = n.userid
RETURN n
```

Also, you can install [APOC Library](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/introduction/) and use the function `apoc.meta.type`, this way:

```
match (n:Users)
where apoc.meta.type(n.userid) = "STRING"
return n
```

Comment: Hi @AwaisTariq,  thanks for accept my answer. I have updated with a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks again   @Bruno

Comment: `apoc.meta.type` has been deprecated. Use `apoc.meta.cypher.type`